# OpenSSL encrypt list of files?

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

**Is it possible to encrypt a list of files with OpenSSL command in Linux** I tried the code below to run a the command on multiple files
(I'm using the command instead of coding because I'm not experienced and I could screw up the encryption)

```
ifstream Data("/home/kali/Desktop/filelist.txt"); // txt file contains files to encrypt

string cmd = "openssl aes-256-cbc -in ";
string files; // files scraped from filelist.txt will be stored here
string outarg = " -out ";
string outfile = "/home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/test.enc"; // encrypted files will all be named test.enc (openssl will rename by defualt)
string key = " -pass pass:testkey";

int main()
{
    while (getline(Data, files)) // To get list of files to encrypt
    {
        cmd += files += outarg += outfile += key += "\n"; // Adding everything together using c_str()
    }
    printf(cmd.c_str()); // replaced with system()

}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
"openssl aes-256-cbc -in /home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/Passwords.txt -out /home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/test.enc -pass pass:testkey"
"openssl aes-256-cbc -in /home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/Images.zip -out /home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/test.enc -pass pass:testkey"
"openssl aes-256-cbc -in /home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/Documents.docx -out /home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/test.enc -pass pass:testkey"
```

**Actual Output(1st is good but the other are messy):**

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -in /home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/Passwords.txt -out /home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/test.enc -pass pass:testkey
/home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/src/Images.zip -out /home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/test.enc -pass pass:testkey
/home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/test.enc -pass pass:testkey
 -pass pass:testkey

/home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/src/Documents.docx -out /home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/test.enc -pass pass:testkey
/home/kali/Desktop/Testdir/test.enc -pass pass:testkey
 -pass pass:testkey
```

Comment: Look at your loop. You expect the initial `cmd` value, `"openssl aes-256-cbc -in "` , to be prepended to each 'line' of your result string, but do nothing to actually make that happen. Your loop is doing *exactly* what you asked it to. You asked for only one `"openssl aes-256-cbc -in "` (the initial one held in `cmd`) and that's exactly what you got in return.

Comment: "// replaced with system()" - Arrgh, nooo, *please* don't *ever* use `system()` - it's a security *nightmare*. Forget it exists.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, Great to know, I'm thinking fork() or execl() is better

Comment: @urbanccladr Yeah, some form of fork/exec can avoid most of the problems of `system`. Not as convenient - more code needed, but can be implemented safer. Mainly avoiding the default shell execution.

Comment: @WhozCraig,  It's been a day without finding a solution, I understood the problem. But how can I actually print the whole command line each line?

Comment: Srsly? `string cmd, cmd0="openssl aes-256-cbc -in ";` then change the loop body to use `cmd += cmd0 += files += ...` etc. My prior comment and/or a simple `std::cout << cmd;` in your loop  as you're building it should be pretty clear where the problem differential was between your expectation vs. actuality.